# create new column using cell formula apache poi

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm working with apache poi,i'm having one issue like add new column using division of two columns, and also want to get in percentage(%)

Here is my input 
[image]

Requested output

[image]

here is java code,

```
public class ApacheCreatePivotTab
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
        XSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet();
        //Create some data to build the pivot table on
        setCellData(sheet);

        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("output.xlsx");
        wb.write(fileOut);
        fileOut.close();
        wb.close();
    }
    public static void setCellData(XSSFSheet sheet)
    {
        Row row1 = sheet.createRow(0);
        // Create a cell and put a value in it.
        Cell cell11 = row1.createCell(0);
        cell11.setCellValue("Names");
        Cell cell12 = row1.createCell(1);
        cell12.setCellValue("utilization_pct");


        Row row2 = sheet.createRow(1);
        // Create a cell and put a value in it.
        Cell cell21 = row2.createCell(0);
        cell21.setCellValue("Michal");
        Cell cell22 = row2.createCell(1);
        cell22.setCellValue("6772.00902935");


        Row row3 = sheet.createRow(2);
        // Create a cell and put a value in it.
        Cell cell31 = row3.createCell(0);
        cell31.setCellValue("Michal");
        Cell cell32 = row3.createCell(1);
        cell32.setCellValue("6118.1434599");

        Row row4 = sheet.createRow(3);
        // Create a cell and put a value in it.
        Cell cell41 = row4.createCell(0);
        cell41.setCellValue("Michal");
        Cell cell42 = row4.createCell(1);
        cell42.setCellValue("5000");

        Row row5 = sheet.createRow(4);
        // Create a cell and put a value in it.
        Cell cell51 = row5.createCell(0);
        cell51.setCellValue("Michal");
        Cell cell52 = row5.createCell(1);
        cell52.setCellValue("5279.50310559");


        Row row6 = sheet.createRow(5);
        // Create a cell and put a value in it.
        Cell cell61 = row6.createCell(0);
        cell61.setCellValue("Henry");
        Cell cell62 = row6.createCell(1);
        cell62.setCellValue("6170.8860759");

    }

}
```

This code give me one sheet on which i have perform operation that will add third column in it

Comment: just round it to 2 decimal numbers.

Comment: Thanks but i want first to perform cell operation using apache poi library in java how can i do this in java

Comment: you want to create new column ?

Comment: yes have to add this in new column

Comment: how you generate the input (the first image)?

Comment: yes i'll share the code

Comment: How come `6772.00902935` in java will become `6772%` in excel ?

Comment: I dont fully understand your question, you want third column right? why dont you just create it by using new Cell instance and put value in it

Comment: Actually this data i have created in not actual one,I'm taking some data from  database adding it into sheet then i have to divide one column by 100 and format it to %

Comment: 6772% might be due to excel has formated it to this, I'm also not getting it

Comment: check the answer

Comment: I'm not getting how i can use it.like I have already sheet created,now i have to read it and then modify it by adding new column which have divided value

Answer (score 1):

To add third column

```
   Row row1 = sheet.createRow(0);
   // Create a cell and put a value in it.
   Cell cell11 = row1.createCell(0);
   cell11.setCellValue("Names");
   Cell cell12 = row1.createCell(1);
   cell12.setCellValue("utilization_pct");
   Cell cell13 = row1.createCell(2);  // create third column
   cell13.setCellValue("After_div and adding %");
```

To make the cell format change to numeric

```
     Row row4 = sheet.createRow(3);
     // Create a cell and put a value in it.
     Cell cell41 = row4.createCell(0);
     cell41.setCellValue("Michal");
     Cell cell42 = row4.createCell(1);
     cell42.setCellValue("5000");
     Cell cell43 = row4.createCell(2);

     HSSFCellStyle styleForNumeric = wb.createCellStyle();
     styleForNumeric.setDataFormat(HSSFDataFormat.getBuiltinFormat("0.00")); // format cell to numeric
     cell43.setCellStyle(styleForNumeric);
     cell43.setCellValue("50.00");
```